# ACL groups with subgroups

Tags: cakephp, permissions, grouping, acl

I have working ACL groups

`-client

-member

-manager`

and need to put them down to ALL group as subgroups

`ALL

  -client

  -member

  -manager`

to add the permissiions to ALL, so 3 other will inherit it,
what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the necessary Users & Groups models and you're gonna use CakePHP's ACL behavior. I also assume that you have the 'acos', 'aros', & 'aros_acos' table.

You need to make your Groups a Tree type:

```
class Groups extends AppModel {
    var $actsAs = array('Tree', 'Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    function parentNode() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and in MySQL, your group table should have these fields - id, parent_id, lft, rght, name(or description). The first four fields are necessary in order for the Tree behavior to work.

In groups_controller.php:

```
function add($parentId = null){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        if($this->Group->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The group has been saved.', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The group could not be saved. Please try again.', true));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('parentId'));
}
```

In User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

var $name = 'User';
var $belongsTo = array('Group');
var $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
    $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
    } else {
        $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
    }
    if (!$groupId) {
    return null;
    } else {
        return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
    }
}


}
```

Now everytime you add a new group or user, the AROS table is automatically updated.
Then you need to set the permissions for each node on AROS_ACOS table. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this in CakePHP.

You could place this code inside groups_controller.php and then run /groups/build_acl everytime you add/delete users/groups:

```
function initDB() {
    $group =& $this->User->Group;
    //Allow ALL to everything
    $group->id = 1;     
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

    //allow managers to posts and widgets
    $group->id = 2;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets');

    //allow client to only add and edit on posts and widgets
    $group->id = 3;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');        
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts/add');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts/edit');        
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets/add');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets/edit');
    //we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
    echo "all done";
    exit;
}
```

I hope this helps. Most of the codes were taken from CakePHP online docs.